# How to do the spacing between checkboxes and values

Tags: html, css, jsp, checkboxlist

In my JSP im populating a list into checkboxes. The issue I have faced is im failing to get the space between the label and the checkbox. I have tried to apply the CSS style using a custom class. But its not working either. What can be done to resolve this?

The view:

```
<c:forEach items="${permissions}" var="permission">
    <div class="check-box checkbox-margin" style="padding-left: 20px">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${permission.checked}">
                <form:checkbox label="${permission.name}" value="${permission.id}" path="checkedPermissions" checked="checked"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <form:checkbox label="${permission.name}" value="${permission.id}" path="checkedPermissions"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The styling :

```
.checkbox-margin {
    text-align:center;
}

.checkbox-margin input{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.checkbox-margin label{
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 3px;
}
```

The resulting HTML view :

```
<div class="check-box checkbox-margin" style="padding-left: 20px">
      <input id="checkedPermissions1" name="checkedPermissions" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1">
         <label for="checkedPermissions1">ROLE_LOGIN</label><input type="hidden" name="_checkedPermissions" value="on">

</div>
```

[image: the checkbox list]

Comment: Try padding `padding-left: 20px;` for the label

Comment: padding left for label

Comment: You mean in the css class? 
 .checkbox-margin label{
   padding-left: 20px;
}

Comment: @JohnDoe921 yes

Comment: Nope it doesnt work

Comment: What's the resulting html from the view code?

Comment: @Sheedo added to the question

Comment: Is there a way to have `input` between the opening and closing `label` tag?

Comment: I dont think so since its been generated by JSP

Answer (score 2):

Remove this css :

```
.checkbox-margin label{
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 3px;
}
```

Use `&nbsp;` between input and label

or

In css

```
.checkbox-margin label{
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution to this, put the `input` and `label` inside a `div`. Then give the div a margin.

```
<body>
  <style>
    .check-box{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    .contain{
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="check-box">
    <h2>Premissions</h2>
    <div class="contain">
      <input id="checkedPermissions1" name="checkedPermissions" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <label for="checkedPermissions1">ROLE_LOGIN</label><input type="hidden" name="_checkedPermissions" value="on">
    </div>
    <div class="contain">
      <input id="checkedPermissions2" name="checkedPermissions" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <label for="checkedPermissions2">ROLE_SOMETHING</label><input type="hidden" name="_checkedPermissions" value="on">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here is a screendump of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5c9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I found that Suraj's solution was most fitting for the issue I was facing.

I was injecting an input into the DOM, to sit alongside existing elements using the following:-

```
var filterOptions = ['001','002','005','009'];
// Inject radio inputs Using filterOptions
$.each(filterOptions, function (ind, val) {
    $('<input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="'+val+'" id="site-'+val+'" checked><label for="site-'+val+'">Site '+val+'</label><br>').insertBefore('#allSiteSelector');
});
```

When doing so, I noticed that the element spacing between the input & labels differed to those for the existing DOM elements.

With the injected elements, there was no gap between the label and input.

The fix was to put a `&nbsp;` between the input and the label.

```
var filterOptions = ['001','002','005','009'];
// Inject radio inputs Using filterOptions 
$.each(filterOptions, function (ind, val) {
    $('<input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="'+val+'" id="site-'+val+'" checked><label for="site-'+val+'">Site '+val+'</label><br>').insertBefore('#allSiteSelector');
});
```

```js
// Set siteid radio inputs Using filterOptions
var filterOptions= ['001']

// Inject WITHOUT NBSP
$.each(filterOptions, function (ind, val) {
    var input = '<input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="' + val + '" id="site-' + val + '" checked>';
    var label = '<label for="site-' + val + '">No Non-Breaking Space ' + val + '</label><br>';
    $(input+label).insertBefore('#sitenameAll');
});

// Inject WITH NBSP
$.each(filterOptions, function (ind, val) {
    var input = '<input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="' + val + '" id="site-' + val + '" checked>';
    var nbsp = '&nbsp';
    var label = '<label for="site-' + val + '">With Non-Breaking Space ' + val + '</label><br>';
    $(input+nbsp+label).insertBefore('#sitenameAll');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-filter-content cd-filters list" id="filters">
  <h4>Site Filter</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="001" id="001" checked>
  <label for="001">001 Site 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="002" id="002" checked>
  <label for="002">002 Site 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="003" id="003" checked>
  <label for="003">003 Site 3</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkClass siteBox" name="sitename" value="004" id="004" checked>
  <label for="004">003 Site 4</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkClass" name="sitename" value="All" id="sitenameAll" checked>
  <label for="sitenameAll">All</label>
  <br>
 </ul>
```